# SANYOU relay wiring for HVAC

Tags: ac, relay

I'm having trouble with a Sanyou SLI-S—112DM relay. I'm using it Normally Open, connected to a 120 V AC compressor.

However, when I applied 12 V AC to the relay coil terminals, the compressor turned on/off several times, and then the relay was busted.

The compressor, transformer, and relay were all incorporated in a circuit of an air conditioner unit. I just wanted to use these components separated from the circuit.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I bought another Sanyou relay and busted it again. I'm very new to circuits, but I thought this was an easy task.

Comment: The coil is supposed to be driven with DC, not AC, see [datasheet](http://www.sanyourelay.ca/public/products/pdf/SLI.pdf). How much current does the compressor pull?

Comment: @ocrdu ThankYou for the response! I guess I must have missed a DC converter in the circuit. The compressor is big, I believe its rated for 15 amps.